# jQuery refuses to trigger explicitly invoked event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

During a radio button's change event, I am explicitly invoking a click event on a dependent set of radio buttons to change the current selection. The dependent radio buttons may need to click other dependent check-boxes depending on their states.

Very quickly, the chained click events stop executing.  jQuery gives up because jQuery.event.triggered becomes equal to e.type in the code below.

```
eventHandle = elemData.handle = function( e ) {
    // Discard the second event of a jQuery.event.trigger() and
    // when an event is called after a page has unloaded
    return typeof jQuery !== strundefined && jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type ?
        jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( elem, arguments ) : undefined;
};
```

The barely decipherable comments do not suggest a link between the above code and chaining click events, but they the code is definitely having an impact.

My problems seem to be resolved if I clear the triggered event before invoking the next.

```
delete jQuery.event.triggered;
$(...).click();
```

(I know the advice against writing this kind of spaghetti code. The code was inherited without unit tests or documentation...)

Am I safe to just delete the triggered event property like this?
What might work better?

Answer (score 0):

Try do not trigger `click`. To change state of `radiobutton` or `checkbox` you can use

```
$('radio-button-selector').prop('checked', true)
```

or

```
$('radio-button-selector').prop('checked', false)
```

Comment: I don't think this triggers the event listeners, which is what I need.